# Most efficient to generate one element of shape

Tags: python, numpy

What is the most efficient way to write `np.ones(x.shape)[0:1]` in NumPy?

Basically, I have an array `x`, but I want to be able to append 1 to the front of it regardless of its shape, so I'm doing this to generate a suitable array of 1s and then passing it into `np.concatenate`.

Comment: What kind of "efficient" are you looking for? Fastest execution time? Least memory consumption? Fewest lines of code? Least algorithmic complexity?

Comment: @skrrgwasme Fastest execution time / least algorithmic complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this to add a column of 1s in front of the array x:

```
x = np.concatenate((np.ones((x.shape[0],1)), x), axis=1)
```